# Website loading times out, images are missing, load half-way, and sometimes appear in wrong places

Tags: javascript, ios, wordpress, timeout, connection-timeout

I've ran into this very peculiar issue where the wordpress website I am working on ([Click to see](http://tomgimbel.com)) , looks and works great on all browsers except Safari on iPhone.

The site seems to be loading and times out half way. Sometimes images appear in wrong places, sometimes they're cut off mid-image. We've tested the site on OSX, Windows, in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and iOS Chrome and it appears to be working great. The interesting thing is that this problem seems to be exclusive to Mobile Safari, consistently across multiple devices from different networks.

Here's are a few examples of what we're seeing:

- [In this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgv4t.png) should be a background image and a menu icon in the nav.
- And [in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEIj3.png) what is that image doing in there? There should be another logo and these should be scrolling right to left instead of being displayed vertically.
- And [in this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsB44.png) Some images don't load at all and some don't load all the way.
- And also [in this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BEnC.png) same portion of the website as above, except nice and crisp, how it should look. This was using iOS Chrome.

We tried isolating the issue by switching over to the default Twenty Fifteen wordpress theme, where we created an image heavy blog post (without any widgets), and the issue persisted.

We've been clearing browser caches and using W3 Total Cache to clear WP cache, but no luck.

Also had the website host, Namecheap, reset the server configs, just in case that would solve the issue, but, alas, no luck either.

Has anyone run into this bizarre issue in the past? Any ideas what else we could try?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does it works now?

Comment: @nanilab It did not—what fixed it for us was switching hosting plans from shared host. Try a shared plan on a different host, or an upgraded plan. Worked for us. Not the best solution...